# How to read specific information from a file into a structure

Tags: c, file, struct

I have a .txt file named question.txt which contains the multiple-choice questions and multiple answers for them in this format :

```
**X question content 
# Answer 1
# Answer 2
...
# Answer n
```

- X is an integer (a number of the chapter from which the question was taken)
- n is smaller or equal to 5

I'm trying to extract the information on the chapter number (X) the question content and the answers of said question and store them into a struct variable like so

```
struct {
    int chapter;
    int qcontent[512];
    char answer[5][256];
}
```

**Below is my attempt I was wondering if there is a different approach to this, maybe a more compact way ?**

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  int chapter;
  char qcontent[512];
  char answer[5][256];
} question;

int main()
{
  question question[100];

  FILE *fp = fopen("question.txt", "r");
  char fline[512];
  int i = -1; // Count question
  int j = 0; // Count answer in a question
  
  while (!feof(fp)) {
    fgets(fline, 512, fp);
    fline[strlen(fline) - 1] = 0;

    if (strstr(fline, "**")) {
      ++i; 
      question[i].chapter = fline[2] - '0';
      strcpy(question[i].qcontent, fline + 4);  
      j = 0; 
    }

    if (strstr(fline, "#")) {
      strcpy(question[i].answer[j++], fline + 2);
    }
  }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Why `while(!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Comment: There's no `group` member in the `question` structure. Did you mean `question[i].chapter`?

Comment: `fline[2] - '0'` won't work if the chapter number can be more than 1 digit.

Comment: You're missing a `}`, so you have `return 0;` inside the loop and it returns after processing the first line of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: There are many errors in the code you have provided. However, I will demonstrate a way to work with such cases.

First, you need to know how the structure information was saved in the file. Lets say, we have the following format.

```
chapter, question, ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4, ans5
datatype: int, char*, char*, char*, char*, char*, char*
```

Meaning, we separate each element by a comma. This can be a problem if your `question` or `answer` element contains comma. In this case, just find a symbol like `|,\` that are unlikely to be present in your `question` or `answer`. The file that we will use to demonstrate the example is [this](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/BchH9yyR8P/)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
  int chapter;
  char qcontent[512];
  char answer[5][256];
} question;

int main(){
  question question[100];
  FILE *file = fopen("question.txt","r");
  
  char buffer[2048];
  memset(buffer, 2048, 0); // initializing the buffer with 0, its always   a good practice to initialize.
  int i=0;
  while(fgets(buffer, 2048, file)!=NULL){
// atoi() = ascii to integer, a function frob stdlib.h
      question[i].chapter = atoi(strtok(buffer, "\n,"));
      strcpy(question[i].qcontent, strtok(NULL, ","));
      for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
        strcpy(question[i].answer[j], strtok(NULL, ","));
      } 
      // The last string will have a \n next to it, so-
      strcpy(question[i].answer[4], strtok(NULL, ",\n"));
      i++;
  }

  for(int index=0; index<i; index++){
    printf("Question on chapter %d:\n",question[index].chapter);
    printf("%s\n",question[index].qcontent);
    printf("Answers:\n");
    for(int j=0; j<5; j++) printf("%s\n",question[index].answer[j]);
  }
return 0;
}
```

You will see this [output](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/VJyRJyWHDQ/) in the screen.

You can learn more here.

[How to read/write 2D array from file?](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-file-examples)

[How does strtok() work?](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/splitting-a-string-using-strtok-in-c)

[How does fgets() work?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fgets-gets-c-language/)

[How does atoi() work?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-your-own-atoi/)

Comment: The file format is part of the question. You can't imagine a new one that fits your need. Revise your code to follow the question.